# Should I use LIKE or CONTAINS on a second column?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, sql-server-2016

I have a table which has 2 columns (`nvarchar(max)` and `varbinary(max)`. The binary column contains PDF documents and the catalog and index are setup to use this column.

The nvarchar column contains a list of id's (eg. "12","55","69", etc). This column can contain 100's of id's so that text would be quite long.

When building a search query, I always use `CONTAINS`, eg:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE CONTAINS(mybinarycolumn, 'keyword')
```

Depending on the search, I might or might not use the secondary column. So I was going to use `IF` to execute a second query, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE CONTAINS(mybinarycolumn, 'keyword') AND
mytextcolumn LIKE '%"55"%'
```

Would I incur a performance hit if I use `LIKE`? Is it possible to combine `CONTAINS` and `LIKE` into one `CONTAINS` which might or might not use `mytextcolumn` in search? (If the text column must be used, it's always and `AND` with the binary column).

Comment: The "better" solution would be to normalise your data. You shouldn't be storing delimited data in your database. Then you don't need a `LIKE`, you can use a simple `=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the normalization option isn't a good one for you...

I'm sure there will be a performance hit.  LIKE is never a high performing operation, and you can't really build any indexes to help you out.  If you are lucky, the SQL optimizer will do the CONTAINS part of the query first and apply the LIKE only to matching results.  (Show execution plan will be your friend here.)

I can't think of a good way to combine the two columns into something that can be searched with a single CONTAINS; anything I've come up with looks like more work than the query as you have it.

You could try putting a full-text index on mytextcolumn and then use CONTAINS on that column as well.  I'm not sure if that will help or not, but it may be worth a try.

I assume the values in mytextcolumn are well-delimited.  If the column contains unquoted values, e.g. '12,23,45,67,777,890' instead of '"12","23","45","67","777","890"', your LIKE condition won't work the way you expect (because '%55%' would match both '11,22,55' and '11,22,555').

Good luck.